# 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'execute' for cursor.execute(statement)

Tags: python, sqlite, database-cursor

```
c = sqlite3.connect(history_db)
cursor = c.cursor

select_statement = "SELECT urls.urls,urls.Visit_count FROM urls,Visits WHERE 
urls.id=visits.urls;"
cursor.execute(select_statement)

results = c.cursor.fetchcall()

print(results)
```

The code above when executed gives an error something like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
cursor.execute(select_statement)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 
'execute'
```

I am new to using python sqlite3 so how do I execute this query with sqlite3 in python?

Comment: you need to call `cursor=c.cursor()`

Comment: Have you tried 'c.cursor.execute(select_statement)' ?

Comment: @MuhammadAsif have you read the db-api doc ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Connection.cursor` is a method, if you don't call it you get the method object itself, not the result of calling it. IOW, what you want is

```
cursor = c.cursor()
```